# SignalR client misses some events at a regular interval

Tags: websocket, signalr

I have a straightforward SignalR setup: OWIN-hosted .NET server and JavaScript client (both @ v2.1.1). The client uses SignalR to synchronize its copy of an ordered event stream maintained in an Rx `ReplaySubject` on the server. When a client connects, it provides a `startAfter` query parameter that is used to initialize an `IObserver` against the `ReplaySubject`, and this observer then sends each event in the observed sequence to the client. Each event has a sequence number, and the client can tell, based on the event sequence number, if any event is missing in the sequence. (Which would be a serious problem in this application.)

The problem is that the client regularly receives only portions of the event sequence. In fact, there is a regular pattern to this. **For every 250 events there is a large gap.** So for example, each test shows that the first gap was from somewhere between 70 and 80 to 250. *Why always 250?* And from there on, the "skip-to" point is always in intervals of **250**; e.g., a gap from 263 to *500*, then one from 511 to *750*, etc.. I have to assume that this is some kind of default buffer size.

Also, the first time a client connects to the server it always receives the entire sequence just fine. It's the subsequent connections that exhibit the regular skipping problem. So it seems like it's a server-side problem, and not a client problem at all.

I then added some checks to the server to ensure that the `IObserver` for each client is seeing all of the events in the correct order. It is. So it seems almost certain that the problem is on the SignalR server side and has nothing to do with Rx.

And finally, I checked to see if the dropped messages were perhaps just being delivered out of order (which I could live with, although I assumed SignalR provides an ordered-delivery guarantee). They are not - the messages just disappear into a void.

If it helps, I'm currently running locally, with IIS Express on Win 8.1 x64 and testing on IE Developer Channel as well as Chrome 36. The connection is using WebSockets. I couldn't find any reference to 250 as a special quantity in either the SignalR source (client or server) or the Rx.Net source.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting? I'd love to find a stable solution before I start building a complicated workaround.

Here's the relevant server-side code:

```cs
public class AllEventsReplaySource
{
    private readonly IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients;
    private readonly ReplaySubject<dynamic> allEvents;

    private AllEventsReplaySource(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
    {
        this.clients = clients;
        this.allEvents = new ReplaySubject<dynamic>();
        // (Not shown: code that generates the input to the ReplaySubject.)
    }

    public void SubscribeClient(string connectionId, int startAfter)
    {
        this.allEvents.Skip(startAfter).Subscribe(e =>
        {
            // (Not shown: code that verifies no skips are occurring at this point for a client.)
            clients.Client(connectionId).notifyEvent(e);
        });
    }

    private readonly static Lazy<AllEventsReplaySource> instance =
        new Lazy<AllEventsReplaySource>(() => new AllEventsReplaySource(
            GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AllEventsReplayHub>().Clients));

    public static AllEventsReplaySource Instance
    {
        get { return instance.Value; }
    }
}

[HubName("allEventsReplayHub")]
public class AllEventsReplayHub : Hub
{
    private readonly AllEventsReplaySource source;

    public AllEventsReplayHub()
        : this(AllEventsReplaySource.Instance)
    { }

    public AllEventsReplayHub(AllEventsReplaySource source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var previousSequenceNumber = Int32.Parse(Context.QueryString["startAfter"]);
        var connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
        AllEventsReplaySource.Instance.SubscribeClient(connectionId, previousSequenceNumber);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing seems consistent with a message buffer overflow. When SignalR releases messages from its buffer, it does so in 250 message fragments by default.

SignalR will buffer at least the last 1000 messages sent to a given `connectionId`. This means that when you send the 1251st message, the first 250 get dereferenced by the buffer. This explains why when a client *first* connects to the server, it receives the entire sequence of messages. You have to send at least 1251 messages to a given client before the buffer will drop fragments. Again, this is all assuming default settings.

While you could increase the [DefaultMessageBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.configuration.defaultconfigurationmanager.defaultmessagebuffersize(v=vs.118).aspx), that probably will not fix your root problem. It seems that you are trying to send messages faster than the server can send them to the client. If you do that continuously, you will run out of buffer space no matter the size.

It's more common to [reduce the DefaultMessageBufferSize](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance#tuning) rather than increase it, since the buffers can consume a lot of memory, especially if you are sending a lot of large unique messages to many different clients.

Your best bet to avoid overrunning the buffer is to have the client send an ACK at least every 1000 messages. Given this, it might be possible to avoid sending over 1000 unACKed messages thereby avoiding this problem altogether.

By the way, you can take a look at [SignalR's message buffer implementation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.1.1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Messaging/MessageStore.cs) yourself if you feel so inclined. Note that the capacity constructor argument is the DefaultMessageBufferSize.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds really promising! I'll look into it in the morning. ;)

Comment: It took a while to design a correct implementation of waiting for the ACKs, but it works! :) Thanks again. I'm currently using an increment size of 50 messages per ACK; 500 seems to have been too much.